# General String splitting Conundrums / Times from Strings C#

Tags: c#

This question is more an open ended what is best practice, or what do you do think is good practice scenario ? I'm trying to get two times, separate out their numbers so they can be placed into a DateTime value.

Example which I think is the quickest and cleanest but I am not sure...

```
string a = "11:50-12:30";
a = Regex.Replace(a, @"[^\d]", ""); //output 11501230
string time_1 = a.Substring(0, 3);
string time_2 = a.Substring(4, 7);
// DO SOME parsing of strings to ints
DateTime Start = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, //enter some separate ints here)
```

But perhaps I can do something like ? and this can't be signifcantly slower can it ? perhaps its quicker?

```
string a = "11:50-12:30"
string a_1 = a.substring(0,4);
string b = DateTime.Today.Year.toString() + DateTime.Today.Month.toString() + DateTime.Today.Day.toString() + "11:50-12:30";
DateTime mytime = DateTime.ParseExact(a_1, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: "I am trying to make it as efficient as possible" - so, you've run a profiler and identified that this is an actual hotspot for performance? Since neither sample would appear to compile/work correctly, how was that done?

Comment: Nothing to do with efficiency but: As you are primarily concerned with times why not parse each part to a `System.TimeSpan` and that could then be added to a `DateTime` instance (using `Add`) if you want it to represent a moment in time.

Comment: If you are not handling 1000s of records, don't worry about performance.

Comment: TryParseExact is what you should be using

Comment: @NoChance dealing with attendance system, with between 10-20 blocks per day and 1000's of people attending, so it'd be getting close.

Comment: So where are these strings coming from? Avoiding receiving them in the first place would be the most obvious optimization, if you can arrange for a more natural representation. From part of your deleted description, I'm starting to suspect that that's how they've been stored in the DB.

Comment: Avoid Regex when possible. Use string builder.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I didn't create the database, I'm a trainee assisting its development, I am reluctant to go stripping parts of the database out in case I broke anything also, they are being pulled from a table in asp.net view that is calculating them from elsewhere in the database but instead of storing it in its original format, it just mutates it away from its original format which I cannot do anything with. + that and I'm traditionally not C# programmer but C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with efficiency but: As you are primarily concerned with times why not parse each part to a `System.TimeSpan` and that could then be added to a `DateTime` instance (using `Add`) if you want it to represent a moment in time.

```
string a = "11:50-12:30";
var parts = a.Split('-');
var time_1 = TimeSpan.Parse(parts[0]);
var time_2 = TimeSpan.Parse(parts[1]);
var start = DateTime.Today.Add(time_1);
var end = DateTime.Today.Add(time_2);
```

*I omitted error checking on the `Split` call to check that there are 2 parts and also on `Parse` which would be advisable. You could also use TryParse but you get the idea.*

Answer (score 1):

You can test performance manually using Stopwatch from System.Diagnostics

```
    string a = "11:50-12:30";

    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    DateTime start = DateTime.Today.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(a.Split('-').First(), "hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay);
    DateTime end = DateTime.Today.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(a.Split('-').Last(), "hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay);
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(start.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(end.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks thats a useful tip.